# Preparing umlauts for PHP Imagettftext

Tags: php, gd, imagettftext

We have scoured the web for a solution to this, but no luck yet...

We are using:

```
$output = strtoupper($input);    
Imagettftext($image, 27, 0, $start_x1, $start_y1, $color, 'font.ttf', strtok($output, ' '));
```

to write the first word of $output to $image.

This works fine in all cases EXCEPT for Ö,Ä,Ü. These get displayed as ö,ä,ü. Our .ttf DOES contain ALL characters.

We have tried converting $input using:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($input); $i++)
{
    $cc = ord($input{$i});
    if ($cc >= 128 || $cc == 38)
        $output .= "&#$cc;";
    else
        $output .= chr($cc);
}
```

but this DOESN'T work... Any ideas how we can fix this??

Thanks in advance for any help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It likely has nothing to do with `imagettftext`. `strtoupper` is locale dependent and furthermore somewhat limited as far as supported encodings go. Use `mb_strtoupper` and tell it which encoding your string is in (likely UTF-8):

```
$output = mb_strtoupper($input, 'UTF-8');
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [mb_strtoupper](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strtoupper.php).

It converts lowercase characters to correct uppercase characters.

Comment: Sometimes it's just to easy.. :)